# Update document on mongo

Tags: mongodb

I read several articles and even the mongo doc, but I do not know why this update, updates the item that does not match the condition 'tests.name': 'testY'.

Follow my update and my document, if anyone can help me, please let me know, thank you.

document:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b687ac27f71ad55cf3e7c3f"), 
"version" : "1.4",
"tests" : [
    {
        "tag" : "develop", 
        "name" : "testX",
        "team" : "PROC"
    }, 
    {
        "tag" : "develop", 
        "name" : "testY", 
        "team" : "REC"
    }
]
}
```

update:

```
db.getCollection('testboards').updateOne(
{
    'version': "1.4",
    'tests.tag': 'develop',
    'tests.name':'testY'
}, 
{
    '$set': {'tests.$.team':'NEW'}
}
)
```

Instead of updating the item 'tests.name': 'testY', the item 'tests.name': 'testX' is updated.

It seems he ignores this condition.

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches)

Comment: Thank you I get it.